# When can composition be viewed as a vector-valued query with differential privacy?

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

Page 33 of [The Algorithmic Foundations of Differential Privacy](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Eaaroth/Papers/privacybook.pdf) gives two examples where a composition of mechanisms can be viewed as a vector-values output, histograms, and fixed counting queries, where the privacy bound can be analyzed by considering the sensitivity of the vector-valued output.

I was wondering about a more general statement; when, generally, can a composition can be viewed as a vector-valued output, and when can't it? Is it true that for any set of fixed, arbitrary mechanisms can be viewed as a vector valued output, where the privacy bound can then be analyzed by considering the sensitivity of the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s always true. A vector is just a formal way as treating an ordered set of elements as an entity in its own right.

Comment: This was my intuition as well, but it felt too simple somehow. Do you know of any situations where the vector view might be disadvantageous, or misleading?

Comment: I think that it might not be helpful when there are dependencies between the components that are hard to untangle. Such cases would be hard to analyse and if a simplifying independence assumption were made, it could be misleading.